# Under what conditions must one rise for his parents?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring, kavod

Is it enough to rise when a parent enters the building or must you rise every time he/she enters your room or passes by your room.

I am interested to know customs for both sefardim and Ashkenazim as I recall seeing a distinction.

Answer (score 1):

[Aruch hasulchan yora daiya 240.24](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&pgnum=198)  (maybe only for **ashkenazim**)

is **not sure if you need to get up every time** (as can be understood from the yerushalmi, and tosfos) **or just 2 times (maybe only when in private)** (once in the morning and once in the evening) is enough (as by a teacher so as to not respect him more then he respects heaven)(as can be understood from the gemoro) , he brings sources for both ways.

From the aruch hasulchan and the shulchan aruch below it can be deduced (if I understood correctly) that anyway **sefardim need to get up before their father many times** (as many times as they meet)

Maybe you are referring to [shulchan aruch yora daiya 242.16 (end)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspxhttp://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6702) where by a **teacher** there might be a **difference between sefardim and ashkenazim**, that sefardim need to get up every time and ashkenazim when in private (others do not see) need to get up only 2 times a day.